How to configure build_runner using multiple builders
I have been using build_runner for generating Built Values. Recently I installed the protoc_builder then my built values stopped being generated.
I am using the following config:
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      - $package$
      - lib/$lib$
      - proto/**
    builders:
      built_value_generator|built_value:
        generate_for:
          - lib/**.dart
      protoc_builder:
        generate_for:
          - proto/**/*.proto      
        options:
          use_installed_protoc: true

Note that when I remove the sources field Built Values get generated but the Protos are not compiled anymore.
